# Get Latest Files from Visual Source Safe

Tags: visual-sourcesafe, visual-sourcesafe-2005

I am new to source control. How can we get all the latest files of a solution. We are team of four and we change lot of files on a daily basis and push them into source control. Sometimes we have to work on the same file and when we get the latest file it affects the entire solution and we end up with getting all the affected files into local version. Can we get a list of files that are updated or can we get all the code changes at one single time. I am using Visual Source Safe 2005.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using VSS in Visual Studio IDE or the explorer client? If in VS, you can perform Get on the solution file to get all the latest files of the solution. If explorer, you can perform Get on the project folder and check Recursive.

If you have multiple people working on the same file, you can enable multiple checkout.
http://www.codepool.biz/version-control/sourcesafe/check-out.html

The [VSS tutorial](http://www.codepool.biz/sourcesafe-vss-how-to) might help.